# Should I branch from branch or create a tag when my new feature depends on previous change?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I am working on an OpenSource project on GitHub where we've agreed on a few rules (listing the relevant ones):

- Merges to master will be done by Pull Requests.
- Every merge to master must be "touched" by at least two people.
- Every new feature will be implemented on appropriately-named branch.

An real-life case that I've enountered went as follows:

1. The need for feature A appeared.
2. I have created a branch `a` and implemented it there.
3. I have proposed a pull request from the branch `a` to `master`, but there's no one to review it right now.

The problem that I've encountered is that there's another feature B I'd like to work on. However, feature B requires feature A changes present. How should I proceed with storing source code for feature B?

My ideas were:

- Create a tag at branch `a` that marks the end of A implementation.
- Branch `b` from `a` and make further changes there.
- Branch `b` directly from `master` and checkout `a` on it.

I am not very experienced with Git, and I think there can be problems with all the above that I'm not aware of, and perhaps there is some other way to manage it sanely. What would be the best solution for the problem that I'm having?

*Note: There's high possibility that `a` will get merged into master before I am done with implementing B.*

Comment: Pull requests may be the way forward for you, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746594/how-to-share-git-branches-that-are-based-on-same-repository/17752569#17752569 It may help. So somebody takes control of the repo and merges pull requests.

Comment: @dirvine I am already using PRs.

Comment: If you use pull requests and then have people responsible for the merge then you can force your rules cleaner I think. Combine this with your tag idea if you wish and still create branches. Then a pull request goes to a branch that's code reviewed and checked, then another dev merges that branch into master. This separates the responsibilities a little better if you want to have some control.

Answer (score 1):

i think this:

> Branch b from a and make further changes there.

is reasonable. you can still merge a on its own.
later, when merging b to master (after a has been merged) there should be no unnecessary conflicts and should you ever decide that you want b but not a (or an alternative implementation from a from another branch) you can fix it "good enough" via a rebase.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural approach is to branch from `A` and start your work from here:

- If the pull request gets accepted as-is, you can continue with the workflow as if you branched from `master`;
- If the branch `A` has been modified, you can rebase your work on the new version of `A` before submitting for review;
- If the branch `A` gets deleted, you can work on a new implementation of the features you need and the cherry-pick from `B` once the new `A` is ready.

Answer (score 0):

If I ignore the fact you are using Git, I would say this resembles what Bazaar pipes are about. So, given the similarity, I would simply branch another branch out of the feature A branch.

**UPDATE**

Bazaar pipes are basically branches that are tied together. The order of pipes in the pipeline is significant. The point is to be able to work on a single feature as multiple patches against main line in parallel and to be able to propagate changes in direction of the pipe line. In your case the pipeline would be master -- feature-A -- feature-B. Later, you can fold each feature as a single change set even though the pipe (feature branch) itself contains many change sets.

It is not the same as your case but it resembles it enough, especially because B depends on A, that I say branch from A to implement B.

Comment: I have no idea what Baazar pipes are. Can you add a short summary that would explain them in context of that question?